# Closing a US credit card after becoming NRA

Tags: united-states, credit-card

I lived in the US for over 6 years and had few credit cards opened. I left the US over a year ago and became a non-resident alien (I'm not a US citizen). At the moment I don't intent to return in any foreseeable future, but I still use one Chase credit card (and pay it on time without carrying over the balance). I'm wondering, whether I must close this credit card or can I just pay the full remaining balance and keep it "dormant"?

Comment: Does it have to be either close it or stop using it? Is there a reason you cannot just keep doing what you've been doing for the last year?

Answer (score 1):

There's no law in the US forbidding non-citizens from having bank accounts or credit cards. As long as the bank has verified your identity and is willing to extend credit to you - it's between you and the bank. Check your local laws, however, some countries have laws restricting/regulating access of their residents to foreign accounts.